# Overriding the New button on a custom Object

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom Object called "Business Development" and when I click the New button I want to auto populate the "Name" Field with the text TBD.  Since I am so new with VF I cant find out how to make this happen.

I created the controller for business development and I was hoping I could pass TBD either through a URL hack in VF or just do a action but I am not sure.  Been searching for hours.. UGHHH

Comment: Can you please share the vf code where you are showing name field.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply use standard functionality and set the field's default value to "TBD"?

Setup> Create> Objects> "Your Custom Object"

From here, edit the properties for your "Name" field with a default value of "TBD".

you will need to create a custom "Name" field to allow default values.  I recommend leaving the standard name field to Autonumber, or use a workflow to populate with Name value with Name__c after create.

Comment: Workflows do not set the value prior to create and I dont see any other functionality that will do it.

Comment: This is not using workflows.  See updated instructions to set default values when "New" is clicked.

Comment: Where would I find the instructions?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The problem with the answer of "or use a workflow to populate with Name__C value after create." I want to autopoulate it before the save otherwise the user has to enter something.

Comment: Apologies, mixed that one up at the end.  I've re-re-edited.   URL hacking will work, but I feel you'll run into issue long term using non-standard functionality.   Using this solution, when a user clicks "New", the page will load with the  Name__c value pre-populated with "TBD.

Comment: I dont think URL hacking will work for a tab button.  Looks like my best option is to either create a name field and have that System name field be a autonumber.  There still must be a way to pass the value of a field in VF.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done through URL Hack. 
 For example 
https://{org}/{url}/e?{ID field}={desired value} 
 you can read this link for more details. Very Nicely Explained. 
http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Comment: Dave, the "New" button is a Button that is on a tab and is a standard button.  URL hacking doesent work for it.  By the way that is a great Link.

Comment: I thought of using VF to do this.  James what your suggesting would work.  I just know that there must be a way to set a vlue to a field using VF.

Comment: There is, but you'll need to override the Standard Button [New] to load your custom page, and here you can pass in the parameter as a default value or let a script pre-populated it in the HMTL.

Comment: Now we are on the same page :)  When trying to override a standard button you have VF and now I go back to my original question In VF how do you auto populate a name field.  I have heard many diffrent ways but no working examples.

Comment: As an example https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_customize_override.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your VF controller's constructor, simply assign 'TBD' to record.Name

```
public class NewCtrl{
    public Business_Developement__c record  {get; set;}

    public NewCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController stdcon) {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest())
            stdcon.addFields(new List<String>(Schema.sObjectType.Business_Developement__c.fields.getmap().keySet()));
        this.record = (Business_Developement__c)stdcon.getRecord();
        record.Name = 'TBD';
    }

    //other methods
}
```